# Azure CDN Standard Microsoft not compressing content

Tags: azure, compression, cdn

I'm using Azure CDN Standard Microsoft, and the files aren't compressed as expected and I don't know why. I've checked their troubleshooting guide and I don't see anything there that would cause trouble.. any ideas? I'm using a gunicorn server as backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the CDN doesn't compress unless the content is already compressed going from the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

compression does depend on the file type itself, to see in more detail please go to this URL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance

What file type is it specifically?